How to add srcset to fotorama PDP images?
I want to add a srcset attribute to the images on the product detail page. So the thumbnail, image and full image get an additionat attribute srcset.
Current:
<img src="image.jpg">
What i want to achieve:
<img src="image.jpg" srcset="image2x.jpg">
I want to do it the right way. The questions is how would I do this? I could not find anything in the fotorama docs.
